# Counter example of monotone union

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, model-theory

I saw this exercise in "[Elements of Abstract and Linear Algebra](http://www.math.miami.edu/~ec/book/)" by E. H. Connell:

Suppose $G$ is a group. Suppose $T$ is an index set and for each $t \in T$, $H_t$ is a subgroup of $G$. Furthermore, if $\{H_t\}$ is a monotonic collection, show that $\bigcup_{t \in T} H_t$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Suppose "monotonic" is defined as follows:

For arbitrary $k$, $l \in T$, either $H_k \subseteq H_l$ or $H_l \subseteq H_k$ (or both).

Then here is my proof:

Suppose $a$, $b \in \bigcup_{t \in T}H_t$, then $a \in H_k$ for some $k$ and $b \in H_l$ for some $l$. So either $a$, $b \in H_k$ or $a$, $b \in H_l$ (or both). Then either $a \cdot b \in H_k$ or $a \cdot b \in H_l$ (or both). Hence $a \cdot b \in \bigcup_{t \in T}H_t$. Therefore $\bigcup_{t \in T}H_t$ is a subgroup.

My question is:

1. Is the above proof correct?
2. I think it looks too trivial. In my opinion, if you have a monotonic collection of sets, all satisfying certain criterion, then "obviously" the union also satisfies that criterion. Can someone give a counter-example?

Comment: Am I correct in saying that the only difference comparing this to your [previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/842628/monotone-union-of-subgroups-being-subgroup) is that there you also ask what the meaning of *monotonic collection* is?